# Project Tango: What is the Constructor export wavefront file format specification?

Tags: google-project-tango, wavefront

After having a look at an exported `.obj` file from the [Constructor App](https://developers.google.com/tango/tools/constructor), I noticed something. While [the official documentation](http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec) only states vertices to have 3 values plus an option weight:

```
v x y z w
```

the vertices in that exported file had three additional values:

```
v -0.09218131 1.425 -0.015000017 0.4627451 0.5372549 0.5686275 1.0
v -0.07500002 1.4277055 -0.015000017 0.56078434 0.6627451 0.7529412 1.0
v -0.045000017 1.429608 -0.015000017 0.81960785 0.627451 0.54509807 1.0
```

I found they are all between `0` and `1`. I suppose that those three additional values representing rgb values as in

```
v x y z r g b w
```

Is that correct?

Related to that: I also noticed that the faces in the file consist of only two indices as in

```
f i/j
```

I suppose, since there never are any texture vertices (`vt`), or possibly they are "replaced" by the `rgb` values, the second slash that the official documentation requires is just omitted? Is that also correct?

Comment: Just random guessing here but could they be uv's?

Comment: @soncis "They" being faces or vertices?
Faces, I don't believe so, they're definitely indices. The first face is `f 1/1 2/2 3/3` and the last one is `f 72029/72029 71977/71977 73378/73378
` (for my file). 
Vertices, I don't believe so either, since there are three additional values and not two.

Comment: I found following excerpt: *"Numbers following the 'f' letter can also be separate with the slash sign ('/'). There is only a maximum of two slashes. If only one '/' is used the first number on the left of the sign, indicates a vertex index and the second number on the right, indicates an index in the texture coordinates array."* - [source](http://www.scratchapixel.com/old/lessons/3d-advanced-lessons/obj-file-format/obj-file-format/). However, the file does neither come with a material file, nor does it contain any texture vertices(`vt`).

Answer (score 0):

I was pointed to [an answer to another question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/31999), mentioning an informal extended format, that indeed uses `rgb` values.

It seems like the absence of a second slash is formally not 100% correct, but acceptable as major rendering software handles it without it just as well.